# HTML image won't appear

Tags: html

I am using the following code to attempt to place an image of myself into my personal website:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <center>
        <img src = "/photos/mainphoto.jpg" alt = "Test Image"/>
        <h1>My Page</h1>
        <hr />
        <p> To be updated.</p>
        </center>
    </body>

</html>
```

The photos directory is in the same directory as the html page.  I have tried placing the photo in the same directory as the html page and it doesn't work.  I have tried using .JPG instead of .jpg.  I have tried executing the code without the alt tag.  I have tried using backslashes instead of forward slashes in the file path.  I have looked for typos in the filename and there are none. I feel like my current code should be working with no problems.  But the image will absolutely not show up. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  I have corrected the code above to fix an elementary mistake, namely including the body inside of my head instead of separating the two.  The picture still does not show.

Comment: Vahe: I forgot to mention that I had tried that before.  Just to make sure I tried it just now and it didn't work.

The directory of my website is simply called "Website".  The location of this HTML file is Website/index.html and the location of the picture is Website/photos/mainphoto.jpg

Comment: Sorry, just deleted my comment,  but look at the top rated answer it should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML structure needs to be:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You are putting the `body` tag inside the `head` tag.

Also, if the images directory is in the same one than the html, you need to remove the first slash, just use `photos/mainphoto.jpg`

So you can try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <img src="photos/mainphoto.jpg" alt="Test Image"/>
      <h1>My Page</h1>
      <hr />
      <p> To be updated.</p>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also I recommend you not to use any spaces before or after the equal signs, these are good practices.

Comment: Thanks for catching the body being inside the head! I fixed that, but the output is the same.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input! I believe I have resolved my own issue, having to do with Windows 10 filesystem hiding extensions. See my response to my own thread

Comment: It has nothing to do with filesystem hiding extensions, you just need to put the correct path `photos/mainphoto.jpg` (without the first slash). I know you are new in Stackoverflow community, here we try to help each other, so then I'll appreciate you choose my answer as the correct one as I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is like this

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

<head>
    <title>My Page</title>

    <body>
        <center>
        <img src = "/photos/mainphoto.jpg" alt = "Test Image"/>
        <h1>My Page</h1>
        <hr />
        <p> To be updated.</p>
        </center>
    </body>
</head>

</html>
```

You have `<body>` element inside your `<head>` element.
It should be like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <center>
        <img src = "/photos/mainphoto.jpg" alt = "Test Image"/>
        <h1>My Page</h1>
        <hr />
        <p> To be updated.</p>
        </center>
</body>
</html>
```

And for that image, the address must start from your html file.
So if you have structure like this

```
 web/    
  index.html    
  photos/
    cutePuppy.png
```

You will have `<img src="photos/cutePuppy.png" alt="Cute puppy">`

Answer (score -1):

Try using the full path of the image listed in its properties.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't appear to have worked.

Answer (score -1):

**FIXED**

In the Windows 10 filesystem, the picture file extensions are evidently hidden.  I had named the picture "mainphoto.jpg", without realizing that the Windows 10 filesystem had already automatically added a .jpg extension, which was hidden in the file structure.  Therefore, the name of the file being referenced was actually "mainphoto.jpg.jpg".

Apologies for the silly mistake, and thank you to everybody who offered suggestions!

Comment: As I told you in the previous message, maybe you put doble .jpg.jpg, but at the end the correct path was without the first slash. I hope you choose my answer as the correct one.

Comment: I must have missed that! Since you suggested the correct answer, I have checked it as such.

Comment: Thank you Tyler :)

Answer (score -2):

Does it show as 404(not found) in the web inspector of the browser you are using. Chances are that the folder with the image and possibly the image it self don't have permissions great enough to allow access. You will have to change the permissions via terminal or possible in the editor(IDE) you are using.